# How to collapsed a nested tree view in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to build a nested tree view containing folders and files in React. When I click on a folder, I want all of the children below it to collapse. It works as intended when I build the nested tree view manually, but when I try to build it recursively, it does not work as expected. Whenever I click on a folder, the entire tree collapses because of where I change `display`.

Here's the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tree-menu-dropdown-m5dflx?file=/src/App.js).

Here's the manually built nested tree view, `SimpleTreeView.js`:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { IconFolder, IconFilePdf } from "./icons";

function ListFileItem({ name }) {
  return (
    <li>
      <IconFilePdf /> {name}
    </li>
  );
}
function ListItem({ name, children }) {
  const [isCollapsed, setIsCollapsed] = useState(false);
  return (
    <li>
      <div onClick={() => setIsCollapsed(!isCollapsed)}>
        <IconFolder /> {name}
      </div>
      <ul style={{ display: isCollapsed ? "none" : "block" }}>{children}</ul>
    </li>
  );
}

export default function SimpleTreeView() {
  return (
    <ul>
      <ListItem name="Folder 1">
        <ListFileItem name="File 1.1" />
        <ListFileItem name="File 1.2" />
      </ListItem>
      <ListItem name="Folder 2">
        <ListFileItem name="File 2.1" />
        <ListFileItem name="File 2.2" />
      </ListItem>
      <ListItem name="Folder 3">
        <ListFileItem name="File 3.1" />
        <ListItem name="Folder 3.2">
          <ListFileItem name="File 3.2.1" />
          <ListFileItem name="File 3.2.2" />
          <ListItem name="Folder 3.2.3">
            <ListFileItem name="File 3.2.3.1" />
            <ListFileItem name="File 3.2.3.2" />
          </ListItem>
        </ListItem>
      </ListItem>
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Here's the recursively built nested tree view, `RecursiveTreeView.js`:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { IconFolder, IconFilePdf } from "./icons";

export default function RecursiveTreeView({ data }) {
  const [isCollapsed, setIsCollapsed] = useState(false);
  return (
    <ul style={{ display: isCollapsed ? "none" : "block" }}>
      {data.map((row, index) => (
        <li key={index}>
          {row.children ? (
            <div onClick={() => setIsCollapsed(!isCollapsed)}>
              <IconFolder /> {row.name}
            </div>
          ) : (
            <div>
              <IconFilePdf /> {row.name}
            </div>
          )}
          {row.children && <RecursiveTreeView data={row.children} />}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Comment: The issue with your RecursiveTreeView component is that you're using a single isCollapsed state variable to control the visibility of all folders. When you click on one folder, it toggles the isCollapsed state, which in turn affects all folders because they all share the same state.

To fix this, you should maintain a separate isCollapsed state for each folder. One way to do this is to create a separate Folder component that maintains its own isCollapsed state.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved my issue. Check out this [frozen codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/collapsible-nested-tree-view-8ldyf2).

Here's the new component, `RecursiveTreeView.js`:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { IconFolder, IconFilePdf } from "./icons";

function ListItem({ name }) {
  return (
    <li>
      <IconFilePdf /> {name}
    </li>
  );
}

function ListFolder({ name, children }) {
  const [isCollapsed, setIsCollapsed] = useState(true);
  return (
    <li>
      <div onClick={() => setIsCollapsed(!isCollapsed)}>
        <IconFolder /> {name}
      </div>
      <ul
        style={{
          display: isCollapsed ? "none" : "block",
          borderLeft: "1px dotted black"
        }}
      >
        {children.map((row, index) =>
          row.children ? (
            <ListFolder key={index} name={row.name}>
              {row.children}
            </ListFolder>
          ) : (
            <ListItem key={index} name={row.name} />
          )
        )}
      </ul>
    </li>
  );
}

export default function RecursiveTreeView({ data }) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {data.map((row, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          {row.children ? (
            <ListFolder name={row.name}>{row.children}</ListFolder>
          ) : (
            <ListItem name={row.name} />
          )}
        </div>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```